# Puppet Dashboard - Getting it to display classes and the add class, group, etc. functional?

Tags: puppet

I extracted the puppet dashboard, configured the clients to the report and got all the reporting stuff working. The classes in the policies are not being parsed into the dashboard.

I also added the following to the masters puppet configuration file and the pathing is correct with the dashboard running on the master.

```
 node_terminus  = exec
 external_nodes = /opt/dashboard/bin/external_node
```

I made sure the firewall is open and I changed the ruby path in the dashboard external node script to use the ruby that was installed (original uses /bin/ruby which doesn't work for ruby installs from source.) Running the external node script directly reports back my nodes, but the parameter listing and class listing are empty.

Looking in the database the class, reports, and parameters tables are empty, and not getting populated. I am guessing this is the core part of the problem.

**How do I get this part of the dashboard working?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood how the dashboard worked. One creates the base classes manually, and then uses the dashboard to group classes and nodes. The policy does not get itself modified in the process except to modify the base classes.

Answer (score 2):

[The Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) can import your puppet classes and environments and also display their rdocs. It needs read access to your /etc/puppet directory, so you need Foreman installed on the puppet master or /etc/puppet can be NFS exported to the Foreman server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of rake tasks in Dashboard which could be useful for maintaining the actual list of classes and groups in dashboard if you are going to manage those outside of dashboard

```
# rake -T
(in /usr/share/puppet-dashboard)
.....
rake node:add                                  # Add a new node
rake node:classes                              # Add/Edit class(es) for a node
rake node:groups                               # Edit/Add groups for a node
rake node:list                                 # List nodes
rake nodeclass:add                             # Add a new node class
rake nodeclass:del                             # Delete a node class
rake nodegroup:add                             # Add a new node group
rake nodegroup:del                             # Delete a node group
rake nodegroup:edit                            # Edit a node group
.......
```